# Nginx downloads tomcat index.jsp instead of serving it

Tags: tomcat, nginx, configuration

I tried to use Nginx vhost a webapp in Tomcat, my vhost config file:

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name *.a.com;

    access_log /var/log/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/error.log;

    root   /opt/javaee/shared/shared1/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/webapps/testapp1; 
    index  index.html index.jsp;

    location / {

       rewrite ^ /testapp1$1 last;


       proxy_set_header   Host               $http_host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
       proxy_redirect     off;
   }

 }
```

When i request `a.com` in browser, it keeps downloading the index.jsp instead serving the page. and when I request `localhost:8080/testapp1`, everything works correctly.  Any insight please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite ^ /testapp1$1 last;` looks completely wrong to me. Everything is rewritten to `/testapp1` in an endless loop. I am surprised it serves anything.

If you would like the `/` (and only `/`) to be mapped to the internal path `/testapp1` use:

```
location = / { rewrite ^ /testapp1 last; }
location / {
    proxy_set_header   Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_redirect     off;
}
```

If you would like everything to be prefixed with `/testapp1` before being sent upstream, use:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header   Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/testapp1/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I totally messed up with `rewrite`, if I want use regex on `location`, how can I redirect to  http://localhost:8080/testapp1/, since the URI is not supported when using regex on `location`

Comment: @perigee You can use `rewrite` inside a regex location and continue processing the request within the same location block by using the `break` modifier. For example: `rewrite ^(.*)$ /testapp1$1 break;` is an alternative solution for case 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard, really appreciate.